# What is major task in test planning?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, test-planning

A test plan is a record enumerating the destinations, target advertise, inward beta group, and procedures for a particular beta test for a product or equipment item. The arrangement commonly contains a point by point comprehension of the inevitable work process. So, what is major task in test planning?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is the problem case?

Comment: I want explanation of test planing major tasks.

Comment: It depends on what you're planning to test, what type of tests you're planning, what kind of development methodology and lifecycle is in use, and a number of other factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question mixed with test **planning** and test **plan**.

Test Planning is the action of discovering how to investigate a particular product - or a part of one.
I have written about [Test Planning Ceremonies here.](http://thatsabug.com/scrum/agile/testing/planning/automation/exploratory/2018/08/21/scrum-testing-plan.html)

The goal of the planning activities is to produce a test plan (see below). The process of such a planning is obviously contextual and, thus, the best ways to do it will be discovered by experimentation.

A Test Plan is the result of a test planning session. It consists of actions to be taken, artifacts to be collected and produced, procedures to be followed, results to be presented, etc.

The exact content - and the format - of a test plan is contextual to the stakeholders (testers, developers, managers, clients, etc) and the product in question. During the planning, the needed content is discovered throughout talking and experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

Test Planning is having different components which combinedly provide a Robust Test Plan. Below are the details:

1. Test Strategy:
   This is a document that communicates the test approach. The test strategy can be developed very early in a project and requires only initial information. Whenever a new type of project is being QAed, the test strategy is one of the most important early test deliverables.
2. High-level Test Planning:
   This is a document that describes the who, what, when, where, and how of the test.
3. Detailed Tests:
   The high-level test plan will show which areas of the application are to be tested.

Major Test Planning Tasks are:
a. Write Test Scripts
b. Define Test Cases
c. Design Test Data
d. Build Test Matrix
e. Determine Test Schedules
f. Assemble Information
g. Finalize Plan

[Top software testing companies](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company#!reasons-to-use-our-services) follow the test planning process in-order to release a robust product.